# No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile

Tags: tridion

Getting "No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile" when I make any OE API calls.

In the cd_core log I can see:

```
2012-05-13 11:59:30,520 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Default storage provider has caching set to: false
2012-05-13 11:59:30,520 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loaded following dao Properties[publication=0, typeMapping=AudienceManagerProfile, storageId=profiledb, cached=false] for publication/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / AudienceManagerProfile / null
2012-05-13 11:59:30,520 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / AudienceManagerProfile / null
2012-05-13 11:59:30,535 ERROR Contact - Unable get contact for requested Identification fields
java.sql.SQLException: No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile
```

I've checked my cd_storage_conf.xml file and it looks correct (I compared it to Nuno's working version from the forum).

Further up in the log it says:

```
2012-05-13 11:59:29,724 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Checking if product Tridion CD Storage is enabled....
2012-05-13 11:59:29,724 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Tridion CD Storage is running in limited mode
```

"Limited mode" sounds bad!
Is this the root cause of the problem or unrelated?

Cheers

Comment: Although I agree in general, one should only accept an answer if it was really the answer to the question so that others can later find use from the same answer if they have a similar question. I'm still not sure what was causing Neil's problem, so doubt my answer will be of help to many stuck in this situation. :-/

Comment: I've been back to support as I think the problem is with licence file itself - are host names case sensitive? I'm happy to accept Puf's answer, I asked whether limited mode was the cause of the error I was seeing and I understand from Puf's answer it is! What's causing "limited mode" is ongoing but not strictly the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the broker runs in limited mode, it means that it couldn't find a license for the 'full' broker. So either it can't find the license file, or the license file doesn't contain a broker license.

When this happens the broker will fall back to using its built-in ItemType mappings, which means it will only support storing them to file system.

It is typically best to point the `cd_storage_conf.xml` to the correct location of your license file. You won't depend on built-in search paths that way and the broker will start using the mappings you've configured.

```
<License Location="/path/to/cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

Comment: Cheers Puf. The thing is, my cd_storage_conf.xml does point to a specific licence <License Location="E:\Program Files\Tridion\config\cd_licenses.xml" /> and that licence does have a key for "Tridion CD Broker". I know the Location path is being used because if I pass a wrong path I see " A LicenseException will be thrown" in the log. So, it must be licence file itself then?

Comment: Are you sure that cd_storage_conf.xml is the one being used? Set logging to debug and check what it says about the conf file it uses before it starts checking the license.

Comment: Yep - log entry: 2012-05-13 11:59:29,708 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Using configuration: file:/E:/Program%20Files/Tridion/config/cd_storage_conf.xml

Comment: Ok. Clearly the broker is switching to limited mode, which means it hasn't found a valid license. We'll need to find out why it does that. Do you have another license file you can try? Does this license work fine on other machines? Did it work in non-limited mode before you added the Audience Manager types?

Comment: Just thought I'd update this with what was causing the broker to switch to limited mode - as usual, user permissions. The account the IIS AppPool was using didn't have read permissions on the licence file or Windows\Temp directory. Once I changed to an account that did - everything worked!

Comment: Good to hear that you found it. Procmon to the rescue?